# Align div side-by-side, but div right with min-width

Tags: css

I want to align two div's side by side. But if the right div which has a minimum width does not fit, then it comes down!

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

div left - width: 250px;
div right - min-width: 200px;

If #sidebar has 400px then:

```
left | right
```

If #sidebar is less than 400px then:

```
left
right
```

test:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #sidebar {width: 30%; background: #FFC;}
    .box {overflow: hidden;}
    .left {background: #F00; float: left; width: 250px;}
    .right {background: #FF0; min-width: 200px; display: inline-block;}
    .image {background: #222; width: 250px; height: 180px; display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="left"><span class="image"></span></div>
        <div class="right">Bla blabla blablabla bla bla<br />Blabla bla blablabla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### EDIT

The #sidebar is 30% of the body of my site!
How do when these 30% represent more or less than 400px?!

#### EDIT 2

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/suShQ.png

Comment: How can `sidebar` be less than 400px when you declare it as having a width of 400px?

Comment: As the # sidebar is 400px, then the div's are side-by-side. But now the # sidebar has 300px?! I set 400px as an example, because in fact this dimension is variable!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width:400px` from `#sidebar` and it will behave the way you want.

With `.left` having `width:250px` and `.right` at `min-width:200px`, your container needs to be at least 450px wide to accommodate them being `left | right`.